# issue regarding flow of php loop

Tags: php, if-statement, break

i have a foreach loop
i am trying to find a match,if a match is found,then can skip from foreach loop
i used break statement in if condition
now i have doubt that if if condition is false then it continues foreach execution?
anybody can clarify my doubt?

this is my code

```
foreach ($s->find('div#results', 0)->find('div.result') as $lifirsts) {

            $name1= $lifirsts->find('h4',0)->plaintext;
            $desc1=$lifirsts->find('span.description',0)->plaintext;
            $desc1=trim($desc1);
            $desc1=  strip_tags($desc1);
            $name1=trim($name1);
            $name1=  strip_tags($name1);

            if (strpos($name1,$exactsearch)!== false || strpos($desc1,$exactsearch)!== false ) {
               //$counter_exact++;

                $flag++;

                break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: `break` breaks your `foreach`. That's 100% sure.

Comment: once your flows enter if then foreach stops. if not it continues looping till last element of array (considering your array does not have match for if condition)

Comment: am asking if condition is false ,then my foreach loop continue?

Comment: @u_mulder am asking if condition is false ,then my foreach loop continue?

Comment: Yes, if foreach-if statement is false it continued the loop and when enter in the if statement if breaked the loop and come out...


So, answer of your question is yes it will continue your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if if statement is false, then it will continue to the loop...

Answer (score 0):

If You just want to terminate the loop execution when a match is found (e.g condition is true then use the following optimized version)

```
foreach ($s->find('div#results', 0)->find('div.result') as $lifirsts) {

            $name1= $lifirsts->find('h4',0)->plaintext;
            $desc1=$lifirsts->find('span.description',0)->plaintext;
            $desc1=trim($desc1);
            $desc1=  strip_tags($desc1);
            $name1=trim($name1);
            $name1=  strip_tags($name1);

            if (strpos($name1,$exactsearch) || strpos($desc1,$exactsearch))
            {
               //$counter_exact++;
                $flag++;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: my doubt is if condition is false my foreach loop continue? have to add continue statement?

Comment: no need to add continue statement it will still continue . .